# ORA-12514 error after restarting the server

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, tnsnames

I have oracle 11g installed on server and .Net oracle clients will access the database.
Till yesterday i was connecting from clients using this connection string:

```
User ID=dbcplas;Password=pwd123;Data Source=(DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS =(PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 172.17.26.7)(PORT = 1521))(CONNECT_DATA =(SERVER = DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME = orcl.cplas3.com)))
```

Till yesterday I was able to use Oracle SQL Developer in the same client.
Today morning we restarted the server for maintanance. After restarting the server, I cannot able to login from client .Net application or sqldeveloper.
**I can able to log-in thru sql plus of server system.**
Apart from that i cannot able to log in by any other means.
Server side sql-developer also not working.
I have give below details from the server:

**lsnrctl services:**

```
    C:\Users\Administrator>lsnrctl services

LSNRCTL for 64-bit Windows: Version 11.2.0.1.0 - Production on 07-JAN-2014 15:
:45

Copyright (c) 1991, 2010, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Connecting to (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=172.17.26.7)(PORT=1521
)
Services Summary...
Service "CLRExtProc" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "CLRExtProc", status UNKNOWN, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
    Handler(s):
      "DEDICATED" established:0 refused:0
         LOCAL SERVER
The command completed successfully
```

**lsnrctl status:**

```
C:\Users\Administrator>lsnrctl status

LSNRCTL for 64-bit Windows: Version 11.2.0.1.0 - Production on 07-JAN-2014 15:20
:42

Copyright (c) 1991, 2010, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Connecting to (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=172.17.26.7)(PORT=1521))
)
STATUS of the LISTENER
------------------------
Alias                     LISTENER
Version                   TNSLSNR for 64-bit Windows: Version 11.2.0.1.0 - Produ
ction
Start Date                07-JAN-2014 13:17:40
Uptime                    0 days 2 hr. 3 min. 7 sec
Trace Level               off
Security                  ON: Local OS Authentication
SNMP                      OFF
Listener Parameter File   E:\app\administrator\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\network\a
dmin\listener.ora
Listener Log File         e:\app\administrator\diag\tnslsnr\cplas3\listener\aler
t\log.xml
Listening Endpoints Summary...
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=172.17.26.7)(PORT=1521)))
Services Summary...
Service "CLRExtProc" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "CLRExtProc", status UNKNOWN, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
The command completed successfully
```

**LISTENER.ORA**

```
# listener.ora Network Configuration File: E:\app\administrator\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\network\admin\listener.ora
# Generated by Oracle configuration tools.

SID_LIST_LISTENER =
  (SID_LIST =
    (SID_DESC =
      (SID_NAME = CLRExtProc)
      (ORACLE_HOME = E:\app\administrator\product\11.2.0)
      (PROGRAM = extproc)
      (ENVS = "EXTPROC_DLLS=ONLY:E:\app\administrator\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\bin\oraclr11.dll")
    )
  )

LISTENER =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 172.17.26.7)(PORT = 1521))
    )
  )

ADR_BASE_LISTENER = E:\app\administrator
```

**SQLNET.ORA**

```
# sqlnet.ora Network Configuration File: E:\app\administrator\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\network\admin\sqlnet.ora
# Generated by Oracle configuration tools.

# This file is actually generated by netca. But if customers choose to 
# install "Software Only", this file wont exist and without the native 
# authentication, they will not be able to connect to the database on NT.

SQLNET.AUTHENTICATION_SERVICES= (NTS)

NAMES.DIRECTORY_PATH= (TNSNAMES, EZCONNECT)


TNSFILES.ORA

    # tnsnames.ora Network Configuration File: E:\app\administrator\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\network\admin\tnsnames.ora
    # Generated by Oracle configuration tools.

    ORACLR_CONNECTION_DATA =
      (DESCRIPTION =
        (ADDRESS_LIST =
          (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1521))
        )
        (CONNECT_DATA =
          (SID = CLRExtProc)
          (PRESENTATION = RO)
        )
      )

    ORCL =
      (DESCRIPTION =
        (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 172.17.26.7)(PORT = 1521))
        (CONNECT_DATA =
          (SERVER = DEDICATED)
          (SERVICE_NAME = orcl.cplas3.com)
        )
      )
```

**tnsping results - orcl.cplas3.com**

```
C:\Users\Administrator>tnsping orcl.cplas3.com

TNS Ping Utility for 64-bit Windows: Version 11.2.0.1.0 - Production on 07-JAN-2
014 15:30:44

Copyright (c) 1997, 2010, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Used parameter files:
E:\app\administrator\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\network\admin\sqlnet.ora

TNS-03505: Failed to resolve name
```

**tnsping results - orcl**

```
C:\Users\Administrator>tnsping orcl

TNS Ping Utility for 64-bit Windows: Version 11.2.0.1.0 - Production on 07-JAN-2
014 15:31:22

Copyright (c) 1997, 2010, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Used parameter files:
E:\app\administrator\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\network\admin\sqlnet.ora


Used TNSNAMES adapter to resolve the alias
Attempting to contact (DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 172.17.2
6.7)(PORT = 1521)) (CONNECT_DATA = (SERVER = DEDICATED) (SERVICE_NAME = orcl.cpl
as3.com)))
OK (1560 msec)
```

Errors:
From .Net Application:
ORA-12514 TNS:Listener does not currently know of service request in connect descriptor.

Why `lsnrctl status` not showing the status of orcl??
I tried starting the orcl services. But its saying already started..
What may be the problem??

Comment: If you can connect through SQL*Plus the database is up, and should have registered even if it started before the listener; but you can force that with `alter system register`. Try that and see if `lsnrctl` now shows the service. If not, what is your `local_listener` parameter set to?

Comment: @AlexPoole I tried lsnrctl.. It is not orcl service. in local_listener there is no value in column 'value'. do we need to set it?

Comment: It [defaults to the server's host name](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/server.112/e17110/initparams116.htm); does the server name still resolve to `172.17.26.7`? (If you look in the log file, `e:\app\administrator\diag\tnslsnr\cplas3\listener\aler
t\log.xml`, you might see the server name it's trying to use). You can set it to use the IP address but that shouldn't be necessary. I assume the IP is static, not assigned by DHCP?

Comment: Actually when it was working previously, the IP was static. But before restart in morning we were trying to configure another network adapter in dynamic ip for some other purpose. from that time only it was giving problem. now what shall i do?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the comments it seems that the [default `local_listener` parameter](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/server.112/e17110/initparams116.htm) is probably trying to use the dynamic IP from your new network adaptor, so it isn't using the same address the listener is using. The simplest way to fix this is probably to manually set that parameter:

```
alter system set local_listener = '(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=172.17.26.7)(PORT=1521))' scope=memory;
alter system register;
```

Or I think you can use a shorter version, but I can't verify that right now:

```
alter system set local_listener = '172.17.26.7:1521' scope=memory;
alter system register;
```

If that works  - that is, `lsnrctl services` now shows `orcl` - and you're happy with it, change the `memory` to `both` and re-execute so it persists across the next DB restart.

Another version of this is to define the listener in the `tnsnames.ora`, and then use that alias for the `local_listener` value; that would maybe make it easier to make changes if the static IP ever changed, as you'd only need to change the `listener.ora` and `tnsnames.ora` (and all your clients, of course), you wouldn't have to modify the DB parameter directly. That's probably only useful if you have different people managing the DB and those files, which is not very likely; but might be a bit neater.

Comment: i have tried the first command. it is working fine now. do i need to run alter system set local_listener = '(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=172.17.26.7)(PORT=1521))' scope=both; what is the use of that?

Comment: It makes it persist. When you run the `scope=memory` version it only affects the running instance. When the DB restarts it will forget that and go back to the `spfile` for its parameters. If you do `scope=both` (or, at this point, `scope=spfile`) then it will write the changed parameter to the `spfile` as well; so on next restart it will still use that setting. [Read more in the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/statements_2014.htm#SQLRF53147).