# Listener supports no service

Tags: oracle

I have checked listener.ora,net manager but its stil showing the error

```
Error:C:\Windows\system32>lsnrctl start

LSNRCTL for 64-bit Windows: Version 11.2.0.1.0 - Production on 01-MAY-2016 23:36:55

Copyright (c) 1991, 2010, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Starting tnslsnr: please wait...

TNSLSNR for 64-bit Windows: Version 11.2.0.1.0 - Production
Log messages written to f:\app\hegde\diag\tnslsnr\hegde-pc\listener\alert\log.xml
Listening on: (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=hegde-pc)(PORT=1521)))

Connecting to (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=)(PORT=1521))
STATUS of the LISTENER
------------------------
Alias                     LISTENER
Version                   TNSLSNR for 64-bit Windows: Version 11.2.0.1.0 - Production
Start Date                01-MAY-2016 23:37:00
Uptime                    0 days 0 hr. 0 min. 4 sec
Trace Level               off
Security                  ON: Local OS Authentication
SNMP                      OFF
Listener Log File         f:\app\hegde\diag\tnslsnr\hegde-pc\listener\alert\log.xml
Listening Endpoints Summary...
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=hegde-pc)(PORT=1521)))
The listener supports no services
The command completed successfully
```

listener.ora:

```
SID_LIST_LISTENER =
  (SID_LIST =
    (SID_DESC =
      (GLOBAL_DBNAME = PRIMARY)
      (ORACLE_HOME = F:\app\Hegde\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1)
      (SID_NAME = PRIMARY)
    )
(SID_DESC =
      (GLOBAL_DBNAME = PRIMARY_DGMGRL)
      (ORACLE_HOME = F:\app\Hegde\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1)
      (SID_NAME = PRIMARY)
    )
(SID_DESC =
      (GLOBAL_DBNAME = STANDBY)
      (ORACLE_HOME = F:\app\Hegde\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1)
      (SID_NAME = STANDBY)
    )
    (SID_DESC =
      (GLOBAL_DBNAME = STANDBY_DGMGRL)
      (ORACLE_HOME = F:\app\Hegde\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1)
      (SID_NAME = STANDBY)
    )
  )
```

listener.ora Network Configuration File:

```
# Generated by Oracle configuration tools.

LISTENER =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1521))
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = hegde-pc)(PORT = 1521))
    )
  )

ADR_BASE_LISTENER = F:\app\Hegde

ENABLE_GLOBAL_DYNAMIC_ENDPOINT_LISTENER=ON      # line added by Agent
```

Comment: Is your database actually running - can you connect locally through SQL\*Plus? If so what is your `local_listener` initialisation parameter set to? And what IP address does `hedge-pc` resolve to?

Comment: Thank you for the reply.Yes I can able to connect database through sql*plus .I didn't set any local listener parameter.

Comment: Does [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20970785/266304) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21555172/266304) help?

Comment: Sir I have tried all that but its not working.Still its showing the same error.Because of this problem I cannot able to do switchover through data guard.

Comment: You've shown the output from starting the listener, and it's normal to see no services then. What does `lsnrctl services` show when it has been up a while, or after you do `alter database register`?

Comment: lsnrctl service its showing all the services but when I stop and start the listener agian it showing same error.

Comment: Yes, that's is the expected behaviour, until the database registers, which can take a minute to happen automatically.

Comment: yea but I have waited an hour and I restarted both listener and database but no result same thing is showing

Comment: You just said it **is** showing all the services. I don't know what you mean. Does it show services only after `alter system register`?

Comment: No sir from the beginning lsnrctl service showing all the services.but when I'm start the listener it showing listener supports no service.

Comment: And that is what I said is expected behaviour. So what does your previous comment about waiting an hour mean?

Comment: Sir before alter system register the listener was showing all the services and after alter system register also its showing the same,but when I'm try switchover to standby database through Data guard it shows listener doesn't have requsted services and it disconnecting from the oracle.

Comment: That seems to be a completely separate issue from the "listener supports no services" you asked about... Maybe you should ask a question about *that* instead, showing the commands you're issuing, the exact error you get, your DG configuration, etc. But please as on [DBA.SE].

Comment: Thank you Sir ,I thought the because of this error I cannot able to do switchover in DG .

Answer (score 0):

When it first starts up, the database [tries to register its service name(s) with the listener](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/network.112/e41945/glossary.htm#BGBFDJHF). If it is unable to do so - for example if the listener is down - then it tries again periodically.

So it is expected that if the listener starts after the database then it can initially say "the listener supports no services", and the there is a delay before `lsnrctl services` shows the database service names, and so there is also a delay before a service name is recognised when you try to connect to it.

It is possible for the listener and/or database to be [configured](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/network.112/e41945/listenercfg.htm#NETAG298) in a way that means the database cannot register, either automatically or manually with `alter system register`. But in your case you are just seeing the expected delay before automatic registration occurs.

Answer (score 0):

Solution is very simple for this error, first, let's understand why this error occurs. It basically has two reasons which are:

1) Your database and service name is not properly set in Oracle environment it should be same everywhere check below parameter values

```
-ORACLE_SID in oracle environment.
-SID_NAME in tnsnames.ora file.
-SERVICE_NAME in listener.ora file.
```

2) Host name/IP address is missing, not correct or spelling mistake, so please check the below.

```
-Check the IP ADDRESS in /etc/hosts file.
-It should be same in listener.ora and tnsnames.ora file
-And it should be able to ping from the local and remote server.
```

Now see I've also faced the same problem and resolved:

please visit this StackOverflow link:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/45065640/6332029

I hope it will help, thanks!