# ERROR:ORA-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error

Tags: oracle, vmware, fusion

I have converted Hypoervisor virtual machine (win 2012 rs with oracle) to vmware fusion virtual machine. The conversion went ok.

But when i try to connect to oracle using sqlplus i get the error
ERROR:ORA-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error

but this error was not happening in the original hyper v machine.

The cloned virtual machine gives this error. I tried renaming the computer and changed all the .ora files. But still the same error.

tnsping is returning OK

any  help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Off-topic, and not much to go on anyway. Is the database up, or just the listener? What doe `lsnrctl status` show; how are you trying to connect; what Oracle processes are there? Are all Oracle services running? Did the machine name or IP address change during the migration, and have you updated any files to match?

Comment: i tried tnsping <sid> and it okey. lsnrctrl status is also doing fine. all the oracle services are running machine name and ip address changed. i have updated all the matching .ora files.

Comment: Does the new machine name resolve to the new IP properly (both FQDN and just host name)? If the database up (which isn't clear yet - `tnsping` only tells you the listener is up) maybe [it can't register with the listener](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20970785/266304), but just a guess at this point.

Comment: Thank you. the new machine has the same ip and name. It resolves both(fqdn and host name). the link what you have given seems to be my issue. I tried testing the service with net configuration assistant and it failed with Connecting...ORA-12514: TNS:listener does not currently know of service requested in connect descriptor. I am not sure how to change the local_listener since i cant login with sqlplus at all.