# ORA-12560: TSN:protocol adapter error when service is running

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, tns

While connecting to database, even using connect sys/sys as sysdba, I'm getting the following error:

> ORA-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error

I've got all my services and database up.

My lsnrctl status:

[image]

I tried everything I found and still got no answers. I reinstalled it 4 times. I'm using Oracle Database 11g Express Edition.

My Environment Variables:

**ORACLE_BASE:** `D:\OracleDB`

**ORACLE_HOME:** `D:\OracleDB\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server`

**PATH:** `D:\OracleDB\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server\bin`

**ORACLE_SID:** `ORCL` (i don't know if it's propper, but i saw somewhere so i added, I don't know what's my SID because i cannot connect anywhere, maybe tha't the case)

What am I doing wrong? It was working a month ago and today when i wanted to do sth it just stopped working. Don't know if I installed something that has conflict with it. How could i check that?

Comment: It would be better to include the status output as text rather than an image. You haven’t shown us how you are trying to connect - which client, what arguments or settings or connection URL you’re using. Are you using hostname `wran` for instance? What IP does that resolve to? You should be connecting with service name XE (rather than a SID), but acccording to that, that service is not actually available. That suggests either your DB isn’t running, or since you say it is, it can’t register with the listener, which may also be IP confusion.

Comment: @AlexPoole im using sqlplus and just trying to connect to DB, so u say it's maybe problem with hostname? i was thinking about that, but it is state after clear installation, i didnt change anything by myself. Localhost:8080/apex doen't also work, I forgot to mention about that

Comment: If you are just doing the connect you showed at the SQL\*Plus prompt that suggests you have TWO_TASK or (as this is Windows) LOCAL set, so look for a tnsnames.ora file and see how the matching entry in there is configured.

Comment: this is how my tnsnames.ora looks like:
https://pastebin.com/6FniPchm

Should i change my host to localhost?

Comment: When i use tnsping xe it says the ping is OK(0msec)

Comment: What do you see if you set ORACLE_SID to XE instead of ORCL; and what happens if you `connect x/y@xe`?

Comment: I suspect the underlying issue might be that your PC’s IP address has changed, or your hosts file entry has changed; and something is still using the old address. If you can connect as sys with ORACLE_SID set to XE, with `connect / as sysdba`, then check the LOCAL_LISTENER value. [This may be revelant](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20970785/266304).

Comment: when i changed ORACLE_SID to XE after connect / as sysdba it says Connected to and idle instance. And after connect hr/hr now it says
ERROR:
ORA-01034: ORACLE not avalaible
ORA-27101: shared memory real does not exist
And as u said yes, i changed my IP address because im not in a different location. May it be the case?

Comment: Then your database is not running. I don’t think an IP change should stop it (or its service) starting, but I’m not entirely sure under Windows. You can try to start it up as sys now, but you might need to find the alert log to see what is wrong. Good luck.

Comment: @Wran ok, i've deleted my answer but i wondered what's your DB_NAME parameter in your (s)pfile? ( really didn't touch, and stays still as ORCL ?)

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan if u say about dbs/init.ora file then yes, it is db_name='ORCL'.

Comment: @AlexPoole my DB is running, i started it with StartDB.bat, but after using startup in sqplus i got buch of errors https://imgur.com/g1b1bjf (Last one says it cannot find a file)

Answer (score 1):

Use *Net Configuration Assistant* to test your connection (listener )
than check the services in your system by:

1. RUN
2. services.msc
3. be sure your serves run (make on restart for the listener )